# changing the directory of an item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

if you run this small project , your'll be asked to input a url and then firefox will pop up and a  music will be downloaded to my project directory...Now i just want to replace the downloaded item from its source path to Desktop but i cant since there is premissionError [winErrpr 31] [winError 32] and i don't know how to fix it...
***myFireFoxDirecoty***  and ***source*** and ***Desktop*** are just paths so i used something else than path not to show the path directory in my questino

```
import wget,os,requests,webbrowser

def visitWeb(myLink):
    url = myLink
    webbrowser.register('firefox',None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(myFireFoxDirecoty))
    webbrowser.get('firefox').open(url)

callMe = input('insert a link :')
r = requests.get(callMe)
callMe = visitWeb(callMe)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print('url is ok')
    url = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
    filename = wget.download(url)
if filename != []:
    #moving the downloaded item from project directory to Desktop
    os.rename(source,desktop)
    print('finished downloading')
```

Comment: You want the file to download to the desktop?

Comment: yes i want it to go to desktop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To move the directory try shutil move method

```
shutil.move(source, destination, copy_function = shutil.copytree)
```